# Is there a standard way to optimize models to run well on different mobile devices?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, pytorch, tensorflow-lite

I’m working on a few side projects that involve deploying ML models to the edge. One of them is a photo-editing app that includes CNN’s for facial recognition, object detection, classification, and style transfer. The other is a NLP app that assists in the writing process by suggesting words and sentence completions..

Once I have a trained model that’s accurate, it ends up being really slow on one or more mobile devices that I'm testing on (usually the lower end Android). I’ve read that there are optimizations one can do to speed models up, but I don’t know how. Is there a standard, go-to tool for optimizing models for mobile/edge?

Answer (score 0):

I will be talking about TensorFlow Lite specifically it is a platform for running TensorFlow ops on Android and iOS. There are several optimisation techniques mentioned on their [website](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/best_practices) but I will discuss the ones which feel important to me.

**Constructing relevant models for platforms:**

The first step in model optimization is its construction from scratch meaning TensorFlow. We need to create a model which can be used exported to a memory constrained device.

> We definitely need to train different models for different machines. A model constructed to work on a high-end TPU will never run efficiently on a Mobile processor.

- Create a model which has minimum layers and ops.
- Do this without compromising the model's accuracy.
- For this, you will need expertise in ML and also which ops are the best to preprocess data.
- Also, extra preprocessing of input data brings down the model complexity to a great extent.

**Model quantization:**

We convert the high precision floats or decimals to lower precision floats. It affects the model's performance slightly but greatly reduces the model size and then holds less of the memory.

> Post-training quantization is a general technique to reduce model size while also providing up to 3x lower latency with little degradation in model accuracy. Post-training quantization quantizes weights from floating point to 8-bits of precision - from [TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/post_training_quantization).

You can see the TensorFlow Lite `TFLiteConverter` example:

```
import tensorflow as tf
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()
```

Also you should try using the `post_training_quantize=` flag which reduces the model size considerably.

Hope it helps.